# Car don't start without jumping it

Tags: starting

I have a new battery, new alternator, and new starter and when I start the car with jumper cables connected it starts right up and when I take off the jumper cables it doesn't start.... what do I do about it or what do I check for??

Comment: Should I change the ground wire and the battery terminals?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please try not to double post questions (duplicate has been deleted.) Have you actually tested the battery, even though it's new, to see if it has sufficient charge to start the vehicle?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is either a bad connection at the battery terminals, or a bad ground.  Make sure your connections to the battery are clean and tight.  The negative terminal should have a heavy gauge wire going to the body and / or block.

Comment: Should I change the battery terminals AND the ground wire??

Comment: @GlennSlater Don't spend money on stuff you may not need. Check what was suggested first. If you have a multimeter do a voltage drop test between the battery terminal and cable end. Make sure your connections are clean and tight. Make sure the ground connections are clean and tight.

Comment: Second on checking the battery connections.  You can also try a jumper from the battery ground to the engine ground (block or cylinder head).

Answer (score 1):

Perform a parasitic draw test. It may just be that something in the car is draining your battery while the car is off.